# Can anyone help fix my code

Tags: java, macos

These lines have errors on them the `bs.show` and `g.dispose` have the error syntax error identifier expect after this token and part of the `g.drawImage` says delete the tokens and the 
says says syntax error decleratorid expected after this token what have I done wrong

```
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

Here is the full code

```
package com.mime.WorldExplorer;


public static final int WIDTH = 800;
public static final int HEIGHT = 600; 
public static final String TITLE = "World explorer(Name not final) Pre-Alpha 0.0.1";
private static final String createBufferStrategy = null;

private Thread thread;
private BufferedImage img;
private boolean running = false;
private Render render;
private Screen screen;
private int[]pixels;
private int i;
private BufferStrategy bs;


public Display() {
screen = new Screen(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
pixels = ((DataBufferedInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData;
}


private void start() { 
    if (running)
        return;
    running = true; 
    thread =  new Thread(this); }



    private void stop() {
        if(running)
            return; 
        running = false; 
        try {
        thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);

        }


    }


    public void run() {
        while(running);
        tick();
        render();

        }

private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)  {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return; 



    }


for (int i = 0; i<(WIDTH*HEIGHT); i++);
    pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];

}

Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();




private void tick() {


    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display game = new Display();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setTitle(TITLE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Running....");

    System.out.println("Working!");

    game.start();


}


}
```

Comment: Please - try and type some proper English in your question. I can't tell what's error message and what's question.

Comment: Step one would be fixing your indentation. Your code is pretty hard to read as-is. Also, please post the full text of any compiler errors you're getting, and indicate exactly which line each refers to.

Comment: There's no way that's the full source code, there's no class declaration...

Comment: the error is that it says on g.dispose and bs.show that an identifier is needed and on the drawImage it says Variabledelorater expected instead

Comment: Double-check that these lines of code belong to a method: count your brackets.

Comment: It isnt the full source codeof what ive written just that page

Comment: All im asking for is some help to rewrite those 3 lines so its right

Comment: You're missing a closing brace (`}`) after `g.dispose`

Comment: Have a look at my answer... not sure if it will help, though it's all about the braces `{}` - you have an odd number of them, and a `;` where you don't need one

Comment: Still got an error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the OSX code - however, it looks to be that you have this:

```
Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

.. sitting outside any method - it doesn't appear to be wrapped in anything...

I would advise that you start from the top and make sure you have matching `{` and `}` braces - that is to say that where you have one open `{` you also have a closed one `}` - when you identify the one that doesn't have an end (or start) then you will find the error in your code.

**I THINK**

You need to change this:

```
private void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)  {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return; 



    }


for (int i = 0; i<(WIDTH*HEIGHT); i++);
    pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];

}

Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose();
bs.show();
```

To This - notice its now wrapped in `{` `}` ok :)

**Again - i do not know OSX, though the syntax below looks correct**

```
private void render() {
   BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
   if (bs == null)  {
       createBufferStrategy(3);
       return;    
   }        

    for (int i = 0; i<(WIDTH*HEIGHT); i++){ // changed ; for {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];    
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();

} // added this here
```

Comment: YES you fixed it thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome :) please mark as answered when you get chance

Comment: It may sound stupid but how?

Comment: There is a blank 'tick' to the left of my answer - just click that and it will turn green :)

Comment: Cant see it? Sorry for the fuss

Comment: Although when i try to run it opens up console and says this:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.awt.image
 And then a load of other stuff that wont fit on this comment

Comment: Start a new question and paste in your entire exception, along with the code it references.